# Get the error "All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string passthrough" and I can't resolve it

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm trying to create a training and predicting pipeline that allows me to train models using various sizes of training data and perform predictions on the testing data, I wrote a function:

```
def train_predict(learner, sample_size, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test): 
    results = {}
    learner = Pipeline(steps=[('tree', DecisionTreeClassifier()), 
                                     ('logistic', LogisticRegression()),
                                     ('naive', MultinomialNB())])
    learner.fit(X_train, y_train)
    predictions_test = learner.predict(X_test)
    predictions_train = learner.predict(X_train[:300])
    results['acc_train'] = accuracy_score(y_train[:300], predictions_train)
    results['acc_test'] = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions_test)
    results['f_train'] = fbeta_score(y_train[:300], predictions_train, beta=0.5)
    results['f_test'] = fbeta_score(y_test, predictions_test, beta=0.5)
    print("{} trained on {} samples.".format(learner.__class__.__name__, sample_size))
    return results
```

and then wrote that code:

```
clf_A = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf_B = LogisticRegression()
clf_C = MultinomialNB()
samples_100 = len(y_train)
samples_10 = int(len(y_train) * 0.1)
samples_1 = int(len(y_train) * 0.01)
results = {}
for clf in [clf_A, clf_B, clf_C]:
    clf_name = clf.__class__.__name__
    results[clf_name] = {}
    for i, samples in enumerate([samples_1, samples_10, samples_100]):
        results[clf_name][i] = \
        train_predict(clf, samples, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
vs.evaluate(results, accuracy, fscore)
```

but got the error:

```
TypeError: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string 'passthrough' 'DecisionTreeClassifier()' (type <class 'sklearn.tree._classes.DecisionTreeClassifier'>) doesn't
```

I tried a lot and did not find a solution, can you help me?

Comment: You are not using `Pipeline` correctly. What are you wanting to do with the three models in there?

Comment: I want to employ several supervised algorithms to model individuals' income using data collected from the 1994 U.S. Census. my goal with this implementation is to construct a model that accurately predicts whether an individual makes more than $50,000